# Electron app runs fine in windows 10 but show white screen in windows 7

Tags: electron, desktop-application

I built a desktop app using electron and used electron packager for it, followed by wix to create a MSI installer.

It works fine in windows 10.

Now when it comes to windows 7, something weird happens.

It installs and runs fine in windows 7 also but shows the white screen. When I mouse over or click the desktop app elements in windows 7, I find that the index.html page is loaded and elements are there. But this white screen is somehow hiding the html behind.

Please let me know if someone know solution for this.